# Putting restrictions on deleting hashtable

Tags: c#, winforms, hashtable

I have a hashtable in my forms. So basically I have 2 button **Add** and **Delete**. When I put info in the textbox and add it adds it in the hashtable. But when I click delete it deletes it and when there's no value in it, it shows an error.
Question:  So what I want to do is that when I put info in **textBox1** which is not added in the Hashtable, it should give an error otherwise if the value is already added, it should just delete it.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Hashtable Info = new Hashtable();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox1.Text;
        string b = textBox2.Text;
        if (a == "" && b == "" || a == "" || b == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Missing Input!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Added successfully");
            label4.Text = a + " " + b;
        }

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string a = textBox1.Text;
        string b = textBox2.Text;
        if (a == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Missing Value");
        }
        else if(Info.ContainsKey(a)) // but this deletes it even if the value has not been added
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + "has been removed");
            Info.Remove(a);
        }

    }
```

For example: If I add 2 in Hashtable and try to delete 3, it will still delete it just because there's some value in the textBox.

Comment: can you refactor your code to use the string.IsNullOrEmpty() method   also wrap your Or conditions separately in my opinion think of order of operation in this case.. also why are you double assigning here `label4.Text = a + " " + b;` in your else statement..?

Comment: on this line `else if(Info.ContainsKey(a)) // but this deletes it even if the value has not been added` why don't you show us exactly what the value is my guess is you're not using the debugger are you sure you are not adding values that meet that condition in the `.Contains()` Method

Comment: Hint ` label4.Text = a + " " + b;` if you have a string like `Mary had a little lamb` it will delete that because it contains " " from what I am seeing .. can you give an example or show what's in your hashtable please

Comment: where is Info.Add(...) ?

Comment: Ok so I have 2 textboxes, one for number and another for name.
For ex - Number = 1 and name = sam.
So now when I try to delete number 1, it deletes the data but when I type 2 in number textbox instead of saying there's no data related with this number. It just gives a message that data has been deleted

Comment: @heringer Info is the name of my hashtable and I am adding values to it.

Comment: @samjohal check my answer and tell me if something is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
Hashtable Info = new Hashtable();

private void AddToHashTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = textBox1.Text;
    string b = textBox2.Text;
    if (a == "" || b == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing Input!");
    }
    else if(Info.ContainsKey(a) || Info.ContainsKey(b))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Hash table already contain this key");
    }
    else
    {
        Info.Add(a);
        Info.Add(b);
        MessageBox.Show("Added successfully");
        label4.Text = a + " " + b;
    }

}

private void DeleteFromHashTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string a = textBox1.Text;
    string b = textBox2.Text;
    if (a == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing Value");
    }
    else if(Info.ContainsKey(a)) // but this deletes it even if the value has not been added
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a + " has been removed");
        Info.Remove(a);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a + " is not part of the hash table");
    }

    //same check here for b
    if (b == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing Value");
    }
    else if(Info.ContainsKey(b)) // but this deletes it even if the value has not been added
    {
        MessageBox.Show(b + " has been removed");
        Info.Remove(b);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(b + " is not part of the hash table");
    }


}
```

I change the code a little bit. You miss some crucial things. Like check if the keys are already exist in the HashTable when you try to add them. If you try to add existing key exception will occur. Also I changed name of the methods, you miss to add the both text boxes in the hash table.